# Logic error in 4x4 canvas drawing

Tags: javascript

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to highlight all my canvases that are drawn from this, the last row seems to be blank or all combined. I am trying to make a 4x4 grid of canvases. What is my logic mistake in this?

```
var count = 0;
while (count < 16) {
    if (count % 4 == 0)
        document.write("<br><canvas id = \"canvas_ \" + count + \" width = \"50\" height = \"     50\"></canvas>");
    else
        document.write("<canvas id = \"canvas_ \" + count + \" width = \"50\" height = \" 50\"></canvas>");
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your code a bit:

```
var count = 0;
while (count < 16) {
    if (count % 4 == 0)
        document.write('<br>');
    document.write('<canvas id="canvas_' + count + '" width="50" height="50"></canvas>');
    count++;
}
document.write('<br>');
```

Other than just improving the way of coding style (e.g. using both kinds of quotes), I've added one more `<br>` at the end, since that's what's causing the last row to not be selected.

Adding a `canvas { border: 1px solid #000 }` makes it look like this:

[image: a]

Comment: if i do count <= 16, then 1 extra one is drawn at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok but it seams that canvas element is not selected when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> only `<br/>` elements. It will work when you add one more `<br/>` at the end. And you have also errors in your code count was inside a string.

```
var count = 0;
document.write("<br>");
while (count < 16) {
    document.write("<canvas id=\"canvas_" + count + "\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\"></canvas>");
    count++;
    if (count % 4 == 0) {
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: one more thing, when i have this code with the above you posted, it says that one of the canvases is null..... 

while(count < 16){

  var name = "canvas_" + count;
  var canv = document.getElementById(name);
   var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
   if (count % 2 == 0){

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

    }else{
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    }
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,50 ,50);
    count++;
    }

Comment: @Kelvin As a guess, it's because there is a space after the underscore in `<canvas id = \"canvas_ \"`. See my answer above, this is addressed there.

Comment: @Kelvin I dind't notice that you have errors in your code, I updated the answer.